# Name Server with Multiple IPs

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, bind, centos6, chroot

We have multiple internet connections attached to my company's network, from different providers, and there are authoritative name servers on the network as well, also with an IP from each of those networks.  The servers have chroot-ed "named" instances, with configurations based on the network.

So Network1 has IP addresses starting with "24.x", while Network2 has  IP addresses starting with "96.x".  The idea behind the chroot named daemons is that the daemon associated with Network1 will return IP addresses based on that network, while the daemon associated with Network2 will return IP addresses based on its network.

Hopefully that's clear.  On to the question.

I want to use RNDC to update zone files and have them propagate to slave name servers on this network.  But how do I configure it so that RNDC knows to reload zone files for Network1 when I refer to zone files on that network (and associated chroot-ed environment)...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would build a different rndc.conf file for each instance of named you're running that contains the proper ip:port combination.  You can then use the `-c` flag with rndc to read the desired config file.

From the rndc man page:

```
  -c config-file
       Use config-file as the configuration file instead of the default, /etc/rndc.conf.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are clearly reinventing the wheel, only that your wheel is square form.
DNS servers have a "view" concept for this. You define multiple view for multiple client subsets. And each view holds and gives unique addresss-space representation to each clients subset. You should read about `view` and `match-clients` statements. And what's more important, this way you won't need the answer to original question.

Comment: Just for clarification: I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel, I've voiced my opinion that this is the wrong way to do things. I don't appreciate the manner of your response, but I do appreciate the content.  I'll look into the afore-mentioned statements, hopefully I'll end up with a far less complex configuration.

Comment: We're not in the kindergarten, nobody here cares about your feelings. You either decide to receive qualified professional help, or keep your feelings safe.

Comment: Professionalism does not imply nor does it necessitate arrogance. Your response would have been professional, minus the first sentence. Once again, I appreciate your help in finding a better approach, as the one in place was clearly misguided.